# Formatting using convertNumber amounts of Primefaces returns me the reverse format?

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a query that is when formatting amounts with a mask goes reverse mask outcome.

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,###,##0.00" />
```

As you can see the formatting of decimal and centesimal goes reverse, I put them to the java code.

```
<p:dataTable id="tablePapeletasPendientes"
        var="item" 
        value="#{cPapeletaInfo.listaInfoPapeletas}"
        selection="#{cPapeletaInfo.papeletaSelected}"
        selectionMode="single"
        rowKey="#{item.cPapele}"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

        <p:column style="text-align: center;" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['nro']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex + 1}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['papeleta.placa']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.cPlaca}" />
        </p:column> 
        ....
        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['papeleta.monto']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.nCuota}">
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,###,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText> 
        </p:column>
        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['papeleta.reinc']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.nReInci}" >
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,###,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column> 
        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['papeleta.gastCost']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.gastosCostos}" >
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,###,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column> 
        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['papeleta.dcto']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.nDescuento}" >
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,###,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column> 
        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['papeleta.abonos']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.abonos}" >
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,###,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column> 
        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['total']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.total}" >
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,###,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>     
</p:dataTable>
```

IMAGE: http://i62.tinypic.com/2usk9d1.jpg

I hope a suggestion to my problem, or maybe use a converter.

Comment: I don't see how this question applies to `java` or `jquery` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma in the `pattern` attribute is merely a way for you to express how the numbers should be separated in the text display. `locale` is what will actually decide which symbol will be used to separate the number. For example, in US locale, `1000` will be displayed as `1,000` but in Vietnam locale, the number will be displayed as `1.000`. The default locale for your server must be similar to Vietnam locale. Hence, `.` was used to separate the thousands place. Just add a correct value for the `locale` attribute to your `<f:convertNumber>`.